# What's the best way of starting a private lab wiki site?

Tags: online-resource, lab-management

My labmates and I were thinking of creating a wiki site for sharing protocols, links to github repos, some metadata and other useful lab related material. Contentwise mostly text, maybe some images, but nothing too heavy in terms of storage. We want to keep it private though since there'd be a lot of confidential information. Can you recommend sites that are most ideal for this purpose?

Edit: free services would be preferred.

Comment: As you are already on github, did you look at their option to create a linked wiki page? See https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/about-wikis.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion! I'm not familiar with any of the advanced features of github but I'm looking at it now. Will have to do some reading to see what it's capable of.

Comment: Have you checked whether your university offers such a service? There must be dozens of groups there who would benefit from the exact same thing.

Comment: Find appropriate university/department/group server. Pick any one of the free wiki platforms. Install and enjoy.

Comment: We decided on github's wiki feature. It requires a pro membership but that's for free thanks to our student status. It seems to accomodate all our needs for now. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear what level of "confidential" you're talking. You're unlikely to find a free site that is sufficiently private for storing, e.g., personal information about people.

Comment: No such level of confidentiality. Just a bunch of protocols and scripts we don't want other people have access to before we publish them.